# Type Casting / Callback Functions

Tags: c++

I am currently experimenting with the FLTK GUI library but am not really sure what is going on with callback functions—specifically the type casting stuff is a bit foreign to me. The example below shows a basic window with a button labeled "Press". When you press the button the label changes to "Done".

The label that is passed to the callback function is declared as type `const char*` and then it is cast to type `void*`, but is it possible to declare this as a `std::string` and then cast to `void*`? I prefer to use modern C++ strings than `char` notation.

Also, is the syntax below the best way of casting from one type to another? I have seen `static_cast<type>()` used before but what is the safest/best way to do a cast from `const char*` to `void*` or vice versa and why? What would C++11 recommend?

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Button.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Native_File_Chooser.H>
#include <string>

void xyz_callback(Fl_Widget* w, void* userdata)
{

  Fl_Button* b = (Fl_Button*)w; //cast widget w to button and assign to b

  b->label((const char*)userdata);  //cast userdata back to type const char*
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  Fl_Window *window = new Fl_Window(340,180);
  Fl_Button *button = new Fl_Button(20,40,300,100, "label");
  button->label("Press");
  button->labelfont(FL_BOLD+FL_ITALIC);
  button->labelsize(36);
  button->labeltype(FL_SHADOW_LABEL);
  button->when(FL_WHEN_RELEASE);

  const char* word = "Done";
  button->callback(xyz_callback, (void*)word); //cast word to type void*

  window->end();
  window->show(argc, argv);
  return Fl::run();
}
```

Comment: but is it possible to declare this as a std::string and then cast to "void*"? Yeah.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Do you want to cast the std::string or a pointer to std::string?

Comment: Well, a pointer to it.

Comment: Welcome to the site. This is a very well-worded question, quite rare among first questions. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(T)a`-style casting, also known as C-style casting, it actually the *worst* way to do an explicit conversion in C++. That's because it's the most powerful—it will happily convert almost anything, easily hiding grave errors. It's the only form of explicit type conversion available in C, and it was inherited as such by C++, but should never really be used in quality C++ code.

The cast of `word` to `void*` is unnecessary—any pointer to object type can be implicitly converted to a pointer to `void`.

The cast back to `const char*` in the callback is necessary, but could be done with a `static_cast<const char*>(userdata)`.

To address the question about `std::string`: that depends on lifetime. You can convert a `std::string*` to a `void*` and pass it to the callback. In there, you'd cast it back to `str::string*` (and then retrieve `c_str()` from it to pass to the `label` function). But you must make sure that the `std::string` pointed to is still alive (hasn't gone out of scope) by the time the callback is called. If you make it a local variable in `main`, you're pretty much safe.

If you do it that way, the code will look like this:

```
void xyz_callback(Fl_Widget* w, void* userdata)
{
  Fl_Button* b = static_cast<Fl_Button*>(w);

  b->label(static_cast<std::string*>(userdata)->c_str());
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  Fl_Window *window = new Fl_Window(340,180);
  Fl_Button *button = new Fl_Button(20,40,300,100, "label");
  button->label("Press");
  button->labelfont(FL_BOLD+FL_ITALIC);
  button->labelsize(36);
  button->labeltype(FL_SHADOW_LABEL);
  button->when(FL_WHEN_RELEASE);

  std::string word = "Done";
  button->callback(xyz_callback, &word);

  window->end();
  window->show(argc, argv);
  return Fl::run();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Angew - that's exactly the type of information I needed to help clarify some things in my head and I'm much happier using the code you suggested. Thanks for taking the time to reply!

Comment: @EdwardJeckyll If an answer solves your problem, you should consider marking it such by *accepting* it (by clicking the green check-mark next to it, at most one accepted answer per question). This marks the question as resolved and gives both the answerer and you some reputation. It's the [Stack Overflow way of saying "thanks, it worked"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

If your callback expects a `void*` than you can pass a pointer to anything. But the callback must know how to handle the argument. It must cast it back to a usable type.

You can change the callback so that it expects a pointer to a `std::string`. If you want to have a `const char*` in the callback you have to pass the C-style string to the callback:

```
button->callback(xyz_callback, str.c_str());
```

Comment: minus 1 -- telling someone to use `c_str()` and not describing the lifetime management issues, esp. in a callback.  Dropping your code into the above question's code would break things horribly.

Comment: @Yakk The callback is called synchronously. The callback have to get the ownership of the data anyway. Passing a pointer to any local variable has the same problem. But this is not part of the question. You can't expect to read a book of programming style here.